# Using Retrofit with a Flex Mobile app

Tags: java, android, apache-flex, air-native-extension, retrofit

I'm working on a Flex Mobile app for Android with a native extension.  I'm trying to use Retrofit in the Java code, but the Retrofit calls are failing.

I have the following interface defined:

```
public interface GitHubService {

@GET("/repos/{owner}/{repo}/contributors")
  List<Contributor> contributors(
      @Path("owner") String owner,
      @Path("repo") String repo
  );
}
```

Then I have an `AsyncTask` invoked from the appropriate point in my Java code.  Its `doInBackground` method looks like this:

```
    @Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
    .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateTypeAdapter())
    .create();

    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setServer("https://api.github.com")
    .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
    .build();

    GitHubService service = restAdapter.create(GitHubService.class);
    List<Contributor> contributors = service.contributors("square", "okhttp");
    for (Contributor contributor : contributors) {
      Log.d("FooTask", contributor.login + " - " + contributor.contributions);
    }
    return null;
}
```

From all this, I'm expecting to see a list printed in LogCat; instead I get the following exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Retrofit annotation found on parameter 1 of contributors
```

Is there a way to make Retrofit work inside a native extension with Flex Mobile?

Comment: Hi did you solve this issue ? cause i am facing the same ?

Comment: The only solution I could find was to rewrite the Java code to not use annotations (any annotations, not just Retrofit).

Comment: If anyone else wants to get this resolved I've logged a bug with Adobe: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=4071110

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This currently isn't possible.  ADT strips all annotations from java classes in its compilation process for dalvik.